# Why ffmpeg-split AVI movie freezes when played

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, avi

I used ffmpeg to split AVI movies like

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:22:33 -to 1:2:3 out.avi
```

But the output file `out.avi` is sometimes weird when played (in MPlayerX, for example) -- it  will stop at the first frame, freezing like a picture, but if I drag the process bar forward, then continue playing at a different place, everything would be fine and the video just goes on smoothly.

I have limited knowledge on AVI format and ffmpeg, can you guys point out what's the problem here? If it's a matter of kerFrame or what?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because with `-ss` after the `-i` you might be seeking to a non-key frame. You need `-copyinkf`, which [the manual describes as](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> When doing stream copy, copy also non-key frames found at the
>   beginning.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c copy -copyinkf -ss 00:22:33 -to 1:2:3 out.avi
```